# Unity 2017.3.0f3 post data not being sent to LAMP server

Tags: php, apache, unity-game-engine, cpanel, lamp

It looks like my cpanel/WHM server has *probably* (though I am not sure what is the cause) been set with some security settings, where PHP is not receiving form data posted from other domains / computers / devices...

I've tested null $_REQUEST (and also $_POST - just in case) dump for post data where the origin comes to the server from another device.

- I have also tried CORS setting all in PHP `header("access-control-allow-origin: *");`
- I have also set in .htaccess in both the parent directory and the directory of the php `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`
- as a sanity check, i've tried it with barebones php, no cookies. this will only print if the script sending post variables is from the same server, but will not work if it's elsewhere  `<?php print_r($_REQUEST)`

Header response from client: [image]

Is there a way not to *stop* but to *allow post data from any source*?

(Also for a sanity check, tested client script from remote device posting to server to work on https://posttestserver.com/ - so it is definitely PHP server not accepting post fields)

Comment: Add these headers in .htacess if you are using apache

Comment: Are you making an Ajax call ?

Comment: nope just a regular http/https call from a mobile device app trying to post to server

Comment: which headers should i add to .htaccess?

Comment: still not letting the post variable go thru...

Comment: is there a way to do this without needing root access to Apache httpd?

Comment: i believe htaccess overrides are already allowed as mod rewrite URLs work fine? could there be other settings?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid why did you delete your comments? they might be helpful to someone else with this issue

Comment: @ina which comments i guess you tagged the wrong guy :)

Comment: hmm not sure who left the comments - had thought it was you to elaborate on headers comment

Comment: Most likely your issue is in your php server side. Maybe the framework/script you are using has some crsf protection enabled or simply emptying POST data after the request has been processed. But without the code is really hard to tell.

Comment: tested also using barebones php - no framework

Comment: Is the cPanel/WHM server behind any kind of proxy, Cloudflare, etc? Any clues in Apache's access logs? Wish I could be more helpful, but those are the only two things I can think to check aside from CORS settings.

Comment: apache access logs show no error and it's not behind a proxy... updating to show header response

Comment: mea culpa... this turned out to be a unity issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, in Unity 2017.3.0f3 `request.chunkedTransfer` (from `request = new UnityWebRequest`) is set to true, setting it to false allows for the php://input stream variables to go through.

However, depending on how you are encoding the form, $_REQUEST and $_POST are still null arrays until `request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` is added...

```
request.chunkedTransfer = false; // just this might work if you are using WWWForm
request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: Great debugging! Seems like an edge case. Thanks for sharing your answer and findings. Hopefully it helps someone else in the future too.

Comment: `request.chunkedTransfer = false;` is absolutely saving my life!

Comment: @MissionMike it was basically analyzing headers from chrome (seems usual?) and then a few different http clients and then trying native C# (whose web modules don't load in Unity's shabby .net 3.5) and the nitty gritty on the header.

Comment: @GoonNguyen your corgi avatar looks familiar! have our corgi's met http://corgi.cam