# php://input is null though url parameters are sent

Tags: php, apache

(I'm trying to debug [why php is not accepting posts from remote sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978874/php-allow-accept-post-data-from-remote-sources), even though allow-access is set in .htaccess)

The input stream appears to be null though parameters are sent...

In an empty file:

`<?php echo file_get_contents("php://input");` in `file.php` returns null when variables such as `file.php?foo=bar` are appended to the .php file...

Should this not return null, as variables/parameters are being sent?

Comment: I think some code reads `php://input` before you. From php.net A stream opened with php://input could only be read once; http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: php://input is the very first line in php file...

Comment: I dont think GET data will show up for input, just POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `file_get_contents("php://input");` will work only with POST requests.

See [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

For the case of query parameters, `?foo=bar` would be available via `$_GET`

Comment: mea culpa! of course... can you take a stab at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978874/php-allow-accept-post-data-from-remote-sources